# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, linq

I've a collection of notes. Depending on the UI requesting those notes, I'd like to exclude some categories. This is just an example. If the project Notes popup requests notes, I should exclude **collection** notes.

```
Func<Note, bool> excludeCollectionCategory = (ui == UIRequestor.ProjectNotes) 
            ? x => x.NoteCategory != "Collections"
            : x => true; //-- error: cannot convert lambda to lambda
```

I'm getting the following error: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'`

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler doesn't infer delegate types for lambda expressions. You need to specify the delegate type using a cast in the first ternary clause:

```
var excludeCollectionCategory = (ui == UIRequestor.ProjectNotes) 
    ? (Func<Note, bool>)(x => x.NoteCategory != "Collections")
    : x => true;
```

The silver lining is that you can use `var` instead of having to specify the type for the variable, so it isn't that much more verbose.